# What MIME type should I use for JavaScript source-map files?

Tags: javascript, html, http, source-maps

I want to add [source maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) to my site, but I'd like to exercise some control over how they're served. What is an appropriate MIME type to use for them?

#### Some data

- The content itself is JavaScript, but not meant to be executed as such.
- CDN.js serves `http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.map` with `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`.
- Google serves `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.map` with `Content-Type: application/json`
- The Source Maps spec states that maps should begin with `)]}` to prevent them from being evaluated as actual JavaScript (and thus exposing cross-site scripting attacks). That makes the file invalid JSON and valid, but un-runnable JavaScript.

Comment: I don't know that there's a standard yet. My gut would say to use something like `application/x-source-map`.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

`application/json` is the best mimetype for sourcemap files.

`application/octet-stream` might work well with browser devtools, however this mimetype is a signal to browsers to initiate a download. This may cause problems for tools like performance analysis tooling or JS exception tracking that attempt to make sense of the source maps.

Comment: OK. I was actually hoping for something more specific so I could write an nginx rule that would lock down access by MIME type. I guess I can match on path and make sure all source maps end in `.js.map`.

Comment: @JamesA.Rosen this is what I did in Nginx: `types { application/json                      map; }`. Just update your mime types configuration and the extension is `.map`.